# Python Sockets: my recv protocol receive all the data when i debug it but not when i run it doesnt

Tags: python, image, file-upload, network-programming, python-sockets

So my project is that I need to send a jpg image from one computer to another computer in the same network. To send the data I split the data into chunks of at least 9999 bytes and then I create a length header that tells the length of the data and I attach it to the start of the massage. here is the code:

the protocol:

```
    import os.path
LENGTH_FIELD_SIZE = 4
PORT = 8820

COMANDS_LIST = "TAKE_SCREENSHOT\nSEND_PHOTO\nDIR\nDELETE\nCOPY\nEXECUTE\nEXIT".split("\n")
def check_cmd(data):
    """
    Check if the command is defined in the protocol, including all parameters
    For example, DELETE c:\work\file.txt is good, but DELETE alone is not
    """

    command = ""
    file_location =""

    splited_data = data.split(maxsplit=1)

    if len(splited_data) == 2:
        command, file_location = splited_data
        return (command in COMANDS_LIST) and (file_location is not None)

    elif len(splited_data) == 1:
        command = splited_data[0]

        return command in ["TAKE_SCREENSHOT","EXIT","SEND_PHOTO"]

    return False

    # (3)


def create_msg(data):
    """
    Create a valid protocol message, with length field
    """
    data_len = len(str(data))
    if data_len > 9999 or data_len == 0:
        print(f"data len is bigger then 9999 or is 0, data len = {data_len} ")
        return False
    len_field = str(data_len).zfill(4)



    # (4)
    print(len_field)
    return True ,f"{len_field}{data}"


def get_msg(my_socket):
    """
    Extract message from protocol, without the length field
    If length field does not include a number, returns False, "Error"
    """
    lenght_field = ""
    data = ""
    try:
        while len(lenght_field) < 4:
            lenght_field += my_socket.recv(4).decode()

    except RuntimeError as exc_run:
        return False, "header wasnt sent properly"

    if not lenght_field.isdigit():
        return False, "error, length header is not valid"

    lenght_field = lenght_field.lstrip("0")

    while len(data) < int(lenght_field):
        data += my_socket.recv(int(lenght_field)).decode()

    return True, data
```

now the protocol works fine when I use the same computer for both server and client and when I debug get_msg on the other computer. when I'm not, it seems that the problem is that the part that recv the header will recv something else after a few successful recv and return an error message.

here are the server parts:

```
import socket

import pyautogui as pyautogui

import protocol
import glob
import os.path
import shutil
import subprocess
import base64


IP = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 8820
PHOTO_PATH = r"C:\Users\Innon\Pictures\Screenshots\screenShot.jpg"# The path + filename where the screenshot at the server should be saved


def check_client_request(cmd):
    """
    Break cmd to command and parameters
    Check if the command and params are good.

    For example, the filename to be copied actually exists

    Returns:
        valid: True/False
        command: The requested cmd (ex. "DIR")
        params: List of the cmd params (ex. ["c:\\cyber"])
    """
    # Use protocol.check_cmd first
    cmd_arr = cmd.split(maxsplit=1)
    command = cmd_arr[0]
    file_location = None

    if len(cmd_arr) == 2:
         file_location = cmd_arr[1]

    if file_location == None:
        return protocol.check_cmd(cmd) ,command, file_location

    else:
        file_location = tuple(str(file_location).split())
        if (os.path.exists(file_location[0])):
            return protocol.check_cmd(cmd) , command , file_location
        return False , command , file_location
    # Then make sure the params are valid
    # (6)

def handle_client_request(command,params):
    """Create the response to the client, given the command is legal and params are OK

    For example, return the list of filenames in a directory
    Note: in case of SEND_PHOTO, only the length of the file will be sent

    Returns:
        response: the requested data

    """

    # (7)
    response = "no server response"
    if command == "DIR":
        response = glob.glob(f"{params[0]}\\*.*" )

    if command == "DELETE":
        os.remove(params[0])
        response = f"{params[0]} was deleted"

    if command == "COPY":
        try:
            shutil.copy(params[0],params[1])
            response = f"{params[0]} was copyed to {params[1]}"
        except FileNotFoundError as ex1:
            response = ex1
        except IndexError as ex2:
            response = ex2

    if command == "EXECUTE":
        subprocess.call(params[0])
        response = f"{params[0]} was executed"

    if command == "TAKE_SCREENSHOT":
        #todo find a way to know and create the locatipn of screen shot to be saved
        myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        myScreenshot.save(PHOTO_PATH)
        response = f"screen shot have been taken and been saved at {PHOTO_PATH}"

    if command == "SEND_PHOTO":
        with open(PHOTO_PATH, "rb") as file:
            file_data =  base64.b64encode(file.read()).decode()
            print(file_data)
            is_vaild_response, img_length = protocol.create_msg(len(file_data))
            print(img_length)
            img_data = ""

            if not is_vaild_response:
                response = "img length data isnt valid"
                return response

            while len(file_data) > 0:
                chunk_data = file_data[:9999]
                is_vaild_response, data = protocol.create_msg(chunk_data)
                if not is_vaild_response:
                    response = "img data isnt valid"
                    return response
                img_data += data
                file_data = file_data[9999:]
            response = f"{img_length}{img_data}"


    return response


def main():
    # open socket with client
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind((IP,PORT))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    # (1)
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()

    # handle requests until user asks to exit
    while True:
        # Check if protocol is OK, e.g. length field OK
        valid_protocol, cmd = protocol.get_msg(client_socket)
        print(f"got message {valid_protocol}")

        if valid_protocol:
            # Check if params are good, e.g. correct number of params, file name exists
            valid_cmd, command, params = check_client_request(cmd)
            print(f"check_client_request {valid_cmd}")
            if valid_cmd:

                # (6)
                if command == 'EXIT':
                    break

                if command == 'SEND_PHOTO':
                    data = handle_client_request(command, params)
                    client_socket.sendall(data.encode())
                    continue


                # prepare a response using "handle_client_request"
                data = handle_client_request(command,params)
                # add length field using "create_msg"
                is_vaild_response , response = protocol.create_msg(data)
                print(f"creat_msg {is_vaild_response}")
                # send to client
                if is_vaild_response:
                    client_socket.sendall(response.encode())



            else:
                # prepare proper error to client
                resp = 'Bad command or parameters'
                is_vaild_response , response = protocol.create_msg(resp)
                # send to client
                client_socket.sendall(response.encode())


        else:
            # prepare proper error to client
            resp = 'Packet not according to protocol'
            is_vaild_response, response = protocol.create_msg(resp)
            #send to client
            client_socket.sendall(response.encode())

            # Attempt to clean garbage from socket
            client_socket.recv(1024)

    # close sockets
    resp = "Closing connection"
    print(resp)
    is_vaild_response, response = protocol.create_msg(resp)
    client_socket.sendall(response.encode())
    client_socket.close()
    server_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the client:

```
import socket
import base64


import protocol

IP = "127.0.0.1"
SAVED_PHOTO_LOCATION = r'C:\Users\Innon\Pictures\Saved Pictures\screenShot.jpg' # The path + filename where the copy of the screenshot at the client should be saved

def handle_server_response(my_socket, cmd):
    """
    Receive the response from the server and handle it, according to the request
    For example, DIR should result in printing the contents to the screen,
    Note- special attention should be given to SEND_PHOTO as it requires and extra receive
    """
    

    # (8) treat all responses except SEND_PHOTO
    if "SEND_PHOTO" not in cmd:
        vaild_data, data = protocol.get_msg(my_socket)
        if vaild_data:
            return data
    # (10) treat SEND_PHOTO
    else:
        pic_data = ""
        vaild_pick_len, pic_len = protocol.get_msg(my_socket)

        if pic_len.isdigit() == False:
            print(f"picture length is not valid. got massage: {pic_len}")
            return

        with open(SAVED_PHOTO_LOCATION, "wb") as file:
            while len(pic_data) < int(pic_len):
                vaild_data, data = protocol.get_msg(my_socket)
                if not vaild_data:
                    return f"img data isnt valid. {data}"
                pic_data += data
            print(pic_data)
            file.write(base64.b64decode(pic_data.encode()))
        return "img was recived succesfully "


def main():
    # open socket with the server
    my_socket = socket.socket()
    my_socket.connect((IP,8820))
    # (2)

    # print instructions
    print('Welcome to remote computer application. Available commands are:\n')
    print('TAKE_SCREENSHOT\nSEND_PHOTO\nDIR\nDELETE\nCOPY\nEXECUTE\nEXIT')

    # loop until user requested to exit
    while True:
        cmd = input("Please enter command:\n")
        if protocol.check_cmd(cmd):
            valid_pack , packet = protocol.create_msg(cmd)
            if valid_pack:
                my_socket.sendall(packet.encode())
            print(handle_server_response(my_socket, cmd))

            if cmd == 'EXIT':
                break
        else:
            print("Not a valid command, or missing parameters\n")

    my_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

here is how the problem looks like:[thi is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWPnH.png)

here is how to needs look like:
[the right way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ze1.png)

thank you.

Comment: To help you better I recommend you post your entire code in here. It's hard for us to help you if we need to take time to figure out what to import, extra code needed, etc.

Comment: ok.  iv added the code. thank you

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to  change get_msg function in the protocol:

```
  while len(data) < int(lenght_field):
    data += my_socket.recv(int(lenght_field) - len(data)).decode()
```

instead of:

```
while len(data) < int(lenght_field):
    data += my_socket.recv(int(lenght_field)).decode()
```